# MVVM ASYNC GUI SLQ Connection

Tags: c#, wpf, user-interface, asynchronous, mvvm

Hello all (Sorry in advance i'm french),
I have a little problem with my code. I try to implement MVVM but my ASYNC function make my program wrong because he open my connection async, get the list of object for binding (So null) and go back in SQLReader but is too late my binding is not refresh in GUI. I'm really new in MVVM system, so i sure i miss something.

my code here (Sorry can found text highlight):

DataBinding XAML :

```
<UserControl.DataContext>
<local:UcGridViewModel/>
</UserControl.DataContext>
```

Here ViewModel Class :

```
    namespace *******.ViewModel
   {
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
    using System.ComponentModel;
    using System.Data.SqlClient;
    using System.Linq;
    using Newtonsoft.Json;
    using DataObject;
    using DevExpress.Mvvm;

    public class UcGridViewModel : BindableBase
    {
        public UcGridViewModel()
        {
            this.InitaliseTreeViewDatacontext();
        }

        IEnumerable<TreeItem> treeItemDataBinding;
        public IEnumerable<TreeItem> TreeItemDataBinding
        {
            get
            {
               return this.GetProperty(()=> this.treeItemDataBinding);
            }
        }

        private async void InitaliseTreeViewDatacontext()
        {
            var listProprieteAscDesc = new ObservableCollection<Dictionary<string, string>>();
            var conn = DataAccess.GetSqlconnection();
            var jsonContextLocal = "\"*******\" : 2";
            jsonContextLocal += "\"*******\" : \"True\"";

            var sqlCmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT JSON FROM *******(" +
                        ApplicationContext.GetsimplifiedStringJsonContext(jsonContextLocal), conn);

            using (conn)
            {
                await conn.OpenAsync();


                var result = await sqlCmd.ExecuteReaderAsync();

                var pastFirstRow = false;
                while (await result.ReadAsync())
                {
                    if (!pastFirstRow)
                    {
                        pastFirstRow = true;
                        continue;
                    }

                    var json = result.GetString(0);

                    var deserializedObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, string>>(json);
                    listProprieteAscDesc.Add(deserializedObject);
                }
            }

            this.treeItemDataBinding = listProprieteAscDesc.Select
                    (
                    d => new TreeItem(d["*******"], d["*******"], d["*******"])
                    );

        }
    }
    }
```

And here my object :

```
namespace *******.DataObject
{
    using DevExpress.Mvvm;

    public class TreeItem : BindableBase
    {
        public TreeItem(string label, string parent, string id)
        {
            this.Label = label;
            this.Parent = parent;
            this.Id = id;
        }

        public string Label
        {
            get
            {
                return this.GetProperty(() => this.Label);
            }
            private set
            {
                this.SetProperty(() => this.Label, value);
            }
        }

        public string Parent
        {
            get
            {
                return this.GetProperty(() => this.Parent);
            }
            private set
            {
                this.SetProperty(() => this.Parent, value);
            }
        }

        public string Id
        {
            get
            {
                return this.GetProperty(() => this.Id);
            }
            private set
            {
                this.SetProperty(() => this.Id, value);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Please anyone can give me some tips, advice, or solution about my probleme? I hope (pretty sur not) is clear guys.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly the goal is to initialize data in your VM asynchrously at the startup of your user control. A contructor can't be async so you can't have async calls in it.

One way to get around this is to have a separate InitializeAsync() function in the VM and hooking it up to the Loaded event of the user control. 
The VM part looks something like this:

```
public class MyViewModel 
{
   protected async Task InitializeAsync()
   {
       // Do async stuff here
   }
}
```

And then in the .cs of the user control:

```
public partial class MyControl
{
    public MyControl()
    {
       Loaded += async (s, e) => await ((MyViewModel)DataContext).InitializeAsync();
    }
}
```

This loads the data asynchrously as soon as the user control is done loading its content.

Edit: You already have your Initialize function separate so all you have to do is making it public and hooking it up to the event. 
Also, you should avoid having void as return type of async functions. use Task instead, [here's why](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj991977.aspx).

Comment: Thank you.I think i'm not clear sadly.. the problem is about my GUI. My control content are never refresh if my databinding source change...

Comment: Ah, maybe INotifyPropertyChanged could be what you're looking for? It's basically a way to tell your GUI that something has changed in your VM. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms743695(v=vs.110).aspx